# Mysql how can I select all orders with both attributes

Tags: mysql

I have a table call orders with the ordernumber and another table call order_detail with ordernumber and product number.

I tried to query:

`Select a.* from orders as a
join 
order_detail as b on a.ordernum = b.ordernum
where b.prodnum ='Bike28B' or b.prodnum = 'ridinggloves'
group by ordernum;`

It will give the the result with orders having Bike28B but not the result with the order have both attributes.

Comment: Having count(*) = 2 -- and we normally use IN() for this

Comment: Since you group by the column `ordernum` the values of all other columns, including `prodnum`, is undefined.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 0):

You have unintentionally stumbled upon mysql's quirky grouping implementation, which does non-standard things. Try listing all columns from

```
select a.*
from orders as a
join order_detail as b
  on a.ordernum = b.ordernum
  and b.prodnum in ('Bike28B', 'ridinggloves')
group by <list every column in order>
having count(*) = 2
```

The having clause ensures *both* child rows were found.

Note also the use of `in (...)` instead of `or`, which will have a much better chance if using an index (if one exists) on that column. I also moved that condition into the join clause, because it's a join condition (although it would work in both places).